# Why would I want .union over .unionAll in Spark for SchemaRDDs?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, union, union-all

I'm trying to wrap my head around these two functions in the [Spark SQL documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD)–

- *def union(other: RDD[Row]): RDD[Row]*

  Return the union of this RDD and another one.
- *def unionAll(otherPlan: SchemaRDD): SchemaRDD*

  Combines the tuples of two RDDs with the same schema, keeping duplicates.

This is not the standard behavior of UNION vs UNION ALL, [as documented in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).

My code here, borrowing from the [Spark SQL documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#tab_scala_3), has the two functions returning the same results.

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
scala> val one = sc.parallelize(Array(Person("Alpha",1), Person("Beta",2)))
scala> val two = sc.parallelize(Array(Person("Alpha",1), Person("Beta",2),  Person("Gamma", 3)))
scala> val schemaString = "name age"
scala> val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
scala> val peopleSchemaRDD1 = sqlContext.applySchema(one, schema)
scala> val peopleSchemaRDD2 = sqlContext.applySchema(two, schema)
scala> peopleSchemaRDD1.union(peopleSchemaRDD2).collect
res34: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Alpha,1], [Beta,2], [Alpha,1], [Beta,2], [Gamma,3])
scala> peopleSchemaRDD1.unionAll(peopleSchemaRDD2).collect
res35: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Alpha,1], [Beta,2], [Alpha,1], [Beta,2], [Gamma,3])
```

Why would I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Spark 1.6, the above version of `union` was removed, so `unionAll` was all that remained.

In Spark 2.0, `unionAll` was renamed to `union`, with `unionAll` kept in for backward compatibility (I guess).

In any case, no deduplication is done in either [`union` (Spark 2.0)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) or [`unionAll` (Spark 1.6)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll).

Comment: Perfect answer really understood its correct unionAll is deprecated and there is union which adds with duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

`unionAll()` was deprecated in [Spark 2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html), and for all future reference, `union()` is the only recommended method.

In either case, `union` or `unionAll`, both do not do a SQL style deduplication of data. In order to remove any duplicate rows, just use `union()` followed by a `distinct()`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from its type signature and (questionable) semantics I believe `union()` was vestigial.

The more modern [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)  offers only `unionAll()`.