# Union of SQL requests by conditions: lost rows? Failed union?

Tags: sql, pdo

I'm trying to categorize reviews of a product to put in a chart. To summarize the results, I'm breaking the result set into four chucks:

```
Score >= 4.5
Score < 4.5 && Score >= 4
Score < 4 && Score >= 3
Score < 3
```

The SQL request can be seen below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reviews 
    WHERE score >= 4.5
    AND id = 4 
    AND live = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reviews 
    WHERE score >= 4 
    AND score < 4.5
    AND id = 4 
    AND live = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reviews
    WHERE score >= 3
    AND score < 4
    AND id = 4 
    AND live = '1'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reviews 
    WHERE score < 3
    AND id = 4 
    AND live = '1'
```

This will then be put in an array. I've noticed the above request returns *thirteen* rows, or the summation of the counts equal 13. I get the below result:

> 10
>   2
>   1

Doing the below request...

```
SELECT score
    FROM reviews
    WHERE live = '1'
    AND id = 4
```

...returns *fourteen rows*. I thought perhaps the result set might be causing issue, but I don't see any. The set of scores is as follows:

> 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9
>   4.8, 4.8, 4.7, 4.4, 4.2, 3.4, 2.6

I'm not sure why that lone row is missing, any ideas, perhaps my syntax is wonky? Why is the final union (where `score < 3`) return nothing?

Comment: If all you want is to count reviews by score range, a case group by can be much faster than unions.

Comment: You can remove the DISTINCTs, since COUNT(*) without group by always returns just one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the last two query both return `1`, and since `UNION` deletes duplicates, `10 2 1 1` -> `10 2 1`. Use `UNION ALL` (see [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, skip the `UNION`, instead use `CASE` to do conditonional counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when Score >= 4.5 then 1 end) AS score_gt_4p5,
       COUNT(case when Score < 4.5 AND Score >= 4 then 1 end) AS score_4_to_4p5,
       COUNT(case when Score < 4   AND Score >= 3 then 1 end) AS score_3_to_4,
       COUNT(case when Score < 3 then 1 end) AS score_lt_3
FROM reviews
WHERE id = 4
  AND live = '1'
```

This way the table will only be read once!