# UNION between select with 0 rows and select with 20745 gives 20740

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, union

In SQL Server 2008 I have a behaviour I don't understand.

I'm doing a `UNION` between two select statements.

- First select returns 20745 rows
- Second select returns 0 rows

When I using `union` bewteen the two selects, I get 20740 rows, I would exspect 20745 as `union` only returns distinct values.

To get the excepted result I used `union all` but there is something I don't understand about it. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: This is how `UNION` works return distinct values only. Use `UNION ALL` instead and get duplicates. Always read manual first before start programming.

Comment: Please read this question. It will explain why this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: How many rows do you get from your first `SELECT` if you use `SELECT DISTINCT` ? 20740 rows by any chance ??

Answer (score 2):

There must be duplicate rows in your first `SELECT` statement. Note that [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) eliminates duplicates from your result set.

If you want to return all rows, use `UNION ALL` instead.

Example:

```
--UNION ALL
WITH TableA(n) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(1)
    )t(n)
),
TableB(n) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES(10),(20),(30),(40)
    )t(n)
)
SELECT n FROM TableA UNION ALL
SELECT n FROM TableB
```

The above will return:

```
n
-----------
1
2
3
4
1
10
20
30
40
```

While the `UNION` variant

```
SELECT n FROM TableA UNION
SELECT n FROM TableB
```

will return:

```
n
-----------
1
2
3
4
10
20
30
40
```

Answer (score 2):

`union` removes duplicate results, regardless of whether they come from two different `select`s or from the same one. If you want to preserve duplicated, use `union all` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   table2
```

Answer (score 1):

First select statement has duplicates :) That's normal behavior.

Try putting a distinct in the first select statement - it should also return 20740 rows.

That should help you better understand what is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you, it turned out that there were duplicates in the select statement. I thought that union only returned distinct rows when comparing the two select, like inner join. Learned something new today thanks :-)