# How to order by union result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that are "merged" with Union:

```
A

union 

B
```

I want the result to be order by a specific column.

for example:

**A**

```
id   sum    dateissue
5     30     1.1.15
8     14     2.4.15
```

**B**

```
id   sum    dateissue
13     30     1.4.12
8     14     4.4.15
```

Desired result after Union **with order by** dateissue column:

```
id   sum    dateissue
13    30     1.4.12           : from B           
5     30     1.1.15           : from A
8     14     2.4.15           : from A
8     14     4.4.15           : from B
```

I tried to do

```
(A)
Union
(B)
order by dateissue
```

but it gives error:

> ERROR:  column "dateissue" does not exist

How can I sort the result of the union?

Comment: Any logic behind that particular order?Shoudn`t 1.1 be ahead of 1.4?

Comment: @Mihai it's ordered by the column issuedate.... look at the year... 1.4.12 comes before 1.1.15

Comment: Provide the code of the queries A and B. A usual `UNION` can have an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Also what type is dateissue

Comment: question is tagged as postgresql.

Comment: What type of column it is I meant it it`s a string even with ORDER BY it wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the first select actually extracts 'dateissue,' ie

```
select id, sum, dateissue
from a
where...

union

select id, sum, dateissue
from a
where...

order by dateissue;
```

To clarify, the 'order by' is applied to the complete resultset (after the union).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
        (
            SELECT id, sum, dateissue FROM A 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, sum, dateissue FROM B
        ) dum
ORDER BY dateissue
```

the order is affect in SELECT *

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT id, sum, dateissue FROM A 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sum, dateissue FROM B
) dum ->

id   sum    dateissue
5     30     1.1.15
8     14     2.4.15
13     30     1.4.12
8     14     4.4.15

ORDER BY dateissue ->

id   sum    dateissue
13    30     1.4.12         
5     30     1.1.15
8     14     2.4.15 
8     14     4.4.15
```

you can use UNION ALL :  [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all) in case of same row

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
ORDER BY dateissue;
```