# UNION DISTINCT in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

When i use `$query2->union($query1)` this is the result sql in laravel:

```
query one ...
union
query two ...
```

How can i have this query:

```
query one ...
union distinct
query two ...
```

In [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions) i saw only `union()` and `unionAll()` methods.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/366529), a `UNION` query by definition is a distinct query (assuming the columns in the two results are the same). A `UNION ALL` returns duplicates if they exist.

So, in Laravel 5.1 (at least), running a union as per the [example in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions) is, by default, distinct:

```php
$first = DB::table('users')
    ->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereNull('last_name')
    ->union($first)
    ->get();
```

I'm not going to repeat what has been said well in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/366529) regarding performance (it's worth reading) but in summary a `DISTINCT` is slower than a `DISTINCT ALL`.