# Date range to get report

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I am creating the report in which I want to date range from "June,2015 or 36 month before current month report was ran, whichever is later"

I have script for which stared from June,2016  and go get 36 back month. AS  Below

```
SELECT  (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
                WHERE 1=1 
                AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -35 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)



SELECT  (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
                WHERE 1=1 
                AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

How i will connect this two script ?

Comment: use UNION ALL  or UNION

Comment: Please choose a correct answer if there is one, otherwise provide follow up information that is not being answered.

Comment: I am looking for the data range "June,2015 or 36 month before current month report was ran, whichever is later" for example if i am running report today it will shows from June,2015 as June,2015 is more than Nov12(36 month back). Now consider i am running same report in Nov 2018 so it will show me Nov 2015 because  Nov 2015 is more than June,2015. Does this make sence to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
            WHERE 1=1 
            AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -35 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
            AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
UNION ALL
    SELECT  (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
            WHERE 1=1 
            AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
            AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

or combine the where clause

```
SELECT  (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
            WHERE 1=1 
            AND (
                CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -35 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                OR
                CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -5 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
                )
            AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION` or `UNION ALL` if you're trying to return these data as the results of a single query.

`UNION ALL` will return all results, whereas `UNION` will perform a `DISTINCT` on the data set.

This is discussed more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).