# combine 2 queries to 1 result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 queries those are as follows:

```
SELECT brt.RequestTypeID, brt.RequestTypeName, brs.RequestStepName AS PreviousStep 
FROM b_Steps bs
INNER JOIN b_RequestStep brs ON bs.RequestStepID = brs.RequestStepID 
INNER JOIN b_RequestType brt ON bs.RequestTypeID = brt.RequestTypeID
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT brt.RequestTypeID, brt.RequestTypeName, brs.RequestStepName AS NextStep 
FROM b_Steps bs 
INNER JOIN b_RequestStep brs ON bs.NextStepID = brs.RequestStepID 
INNER JOIN b_RequestType brt ON bs.RequestTypeID = brt.RequestTypeID
```

How would I combine 2 queries and return result like this:

```
| RequestTypeName | PreviousStep | NextStep      |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Buy good        | Login        | Add into cart |
```

Comment: whats the primary key in `steps`?

Comment: the table b_Steps: RequestTypeID | RequestStepID | NextStepID (PK)

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
select a.RequestTypeName, a.PreviousStep, b.NextStep
from
(SELECT brt.RequestTypeID, brt.RequestTypeName, brs.RequestStepName AS PreviousStep 
FROM b_Steps bs 
INNER JOIN b_RequestStep brs ON bs.RequestStepID = brs.RequestStepID 
INNER JOIN b_RequestType brt ON bs.RequestTypeID = brt.RequestTypeID) as a
inner join 
(SELECT brt.RequestTypeID, brt.RequestTypeName, brs.RequestStepName AS NextStep 
FROM b_Steps bs 
INNER JOIN b_RequestStep brs ON bs.NextStepID = brs.RequestStepID 
INNER JOIN b_RequestType brt ON bs.RequestTypeID = brt.RequestTypeID) as b
on a.RequestTypeID = b.RequestTypeID
```

Comment: hj PK20, It is duplicated

Comment: you want duplicates? Read more about UNION and UNION ALL [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Answer (score 0):

seams to be an easy one but maybe i miss something:

```
SELECT brt.RequestTypeID, brt.RequestTypeName
,      brsp.RequestStepName AS PreviousStep 
,      brsn.RequestStepName AS NextStep 
FROM b_Steps bs
INNER JOIN b_RequestType brt ON bs.RequestTypeID = brt.RequestTypeID
LEFT JOIN b_RequestStep brsp ON bs.RequestStepID = brsp.RequestStepID 
LEFT JOIN b_RequestStep brsn ON bs.NextStepID = brsn.RequestStepID
```

i don't know if you have steps without a previous one or a next one, i used a left join in both cases.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you so much A ツ