# Output multiple queries to same table/file?

Tags: sql, dbvisualizer, intersystems-cache

I have a bunch of very simple `SELECT` statements.  I would like to output them all to the same resultset (UI table or file).  Here is the most recent thing I tried:

```
@export on;
@export set filename="c:\test.csv";
@export set CsvColumnDelimiter=",";
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 2;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 3;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 4;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 5;
@export off;
```

Obviously the CSV file only contains ID 5 because it's just overwriting.  Is there any way to append?  Or, is there any `SQL` option outside of DBVis that will allow me to execute all these SQL queries into one result set?

Comment: are you able to UNION your SELECT statements so there is one result set?

Comment: Looks like that's what I needed.  Want  to post an answer?  Or find a duplicate (now that I know it's a simple command)

Comment: Not related to your question, but `select top n` queries without an order by clause might not yield the desired results.

Comment: Yeah this was a truncated example.  Thanks for the note though.

Comment: For the **@export set** command, add parameter **AppendFile="true"** and you will get all result sets in the file. Read more in: http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG92/Exporting+Query+Results

Comment: Awesome @roger, but would it include the column headers repeatedly as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott, try:

```
@export on;
@export set filename="<outputfile.csv>" appendfile="true";
select * from tab;
@export set CsvIncludeColumnHeader="false";
select * from tab;
select * from tab;
```

This will export the first result set with column headers and the following result sets without column headers.

Comment: Thanks @roger! Are you the dev?

Comment: Yes I am in the DbVisualizer team

Comment: Awesome, keep up the great work! I love the product.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to return one result set, using [UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName WHERE ID = 5;
```

Comment: So I did `UNION` and it seems to work.  What would be the difference?

Comment: To clarify, with `UNION` I get 5 results, as expected.  What would/should I see with UNION ALL?  Would there be any difference in this example?

Comment: An ordinary UNION eliminates duplicate rows (all values identical) from the result. A UNION ALL preserves duplicate rows in the result. http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_union#RSQL_B65538

Comment: I linked `UNION ALL` in my answer with the explanation of the difference.  I'm assuming since you're selecting * by ID that the results would never have duplicates.  Thus, the UNION ALL.