# How to combine the two SQL query results into one table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SearchResult
(     V_ID IN VARCHAR2
      , V_REFCUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS

BEGIN
  DECLARE CNT INT;

  BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT 
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
  WHERE T1.ID = V_ID;

  IF (CNT > 0) THEN
  OPEN V_REFCUR FOR  
  SELECT T1.TYPE
  FROM TABLE T1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
  WHERE T1.ID = V_ID AND T1.TYPE IS NOT NULL;


  ELSE 
  OPEN V_REFCUR FOR  
  SELECT 
     T3.NAME||T1.TYPE
     FROM TABLE3 T3
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID= T3.ID
     INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
     AND TI.TYPE IS NOT NULL AND T1.ID = V_ID;

  END IF;
  END;

   BEGIN
   OPEN V_REFCUR FOR
    SELECT
    T1.NAME
    , T1.ADDRESS
    FROM TABLE1 T1
    WHERE T1.ID = V_ID

 END;
END SearchResult
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code so it is readable.

Comment: You should not expect people to reverse engineer your table schema from the code you are posting. Please include all details (source and destination tables schema).

Comment: ok, i had formatted it already.. thanks

Comment: @Filburt, i just want to know the method on how to combine the two query, because if i run the above query in oracle, it always display the result of second query only.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

To combine results of separate queries into the same table you have several options available to you:

- Combine both queries into one by using a [`Union`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union.php) or a [`Union all`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union_all.php) depending on whether you want to [exclude duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).
- Use a temp table to break apart your queries into 2 separate [`Insert`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) statements and then return the results of the temp table.

Comment: since both of my queries have different column number, so i cannot use union or union all. Do u have other suggestion? thanks

Comment: I'm confused then... how do you expect to insert both query results into the same table if they follow a different structure? Ultimately, finding a consistent result pattern needs to be the first problem you tackle before trying to combine your queries.

Comment: or can u show me how to do it based on my code? i had ran the above code and the result only show the second query.. thanks

Comment: actually the records will  based on second query and only get from table1, but got one column, 'type' need to compare with another table to get its record

Comment: You have three "open" statements. The first two are conditional on the count at the top, but the third gets executed regardless, so I would be surprised if you see anything other than that last result set. btw you have more declare/begin/ends than you need. And for some reason all your code has gone uppercase.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: thanks, you had got my idea correctly. Now my problem, the third will execute regardless, but i want the results from the first two conditional statement combine with the third one.. Can you teach me how to do it?