# Where do I start to optimize this SQL Query?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this sql query delivered from a customer which we need to performance optimize.

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction to where to start looking for optimizing the following query?

The query on my local machine takes about 6-7 seconds, but on the users it´s about 30 seconds, It executes on a mssql 2008r2

Thanks!

```
var query = @"


 DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(250)
 set @SearchString = '1811820001'

                    ;with BaseSelectorCTE (ID) as 
                    (
                        SELECT ID FROM BaseCases b
                            where 
                                b.CPR like @SearchString
                            OR  (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName) like @SearchString
                            OR  b.CustomerInfo_InstitutionName like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from FlexjobCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from DisabledAssistantCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from AdultStudentCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from DiseaseCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from MaternityCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from MiscellaneousCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select ID from WageSubsidyCase
                            where Kommune like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select w.ID from WageSubsidyCase w inner join JobCenters j on
                                w.JobcenterID = j.ID
                            where
                                j.Name like @SearchString
                        UNION
                        Select a.ID from AdultStudentCase a inner join JobCenters j on
                                a.JobcenterID = j.ID
                            where
                                j.Name like @SearchString
                    )
                    --
                    -- Select BaseCases mapped to result type
                    --
                    ,ResultSelectorCTE AS 
                    (
                        select 
                            bc.Id as CaseID, 
                            bc.ChildCaseName, 
                            bc.CPR, 
                            bc.FirstName, 
                            bc.LastName, 
                            bc.CustomerInfo_CustomerInfoID as CustomerInfoID,
                            bc.CustomerInfo_InstitutionName as InstitutionName,
                            bc.CaseDeadline, 
                            bc.StatusID,
                            cs.Name as [StatusName],
                            cs.Owner as [StatusOwner],
                            bc.MetaData_Updated as [LastChange],
                            bc.LastActionDay,
                            ,CASE bc.StatusID WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as SidstePeriodeSoegt
                        from BaseCases bc 
                            inner join CaseStatus cs ON
                                bc.StatusID = cs.ID
                            inner join BaseSelectorCTE bsCTE ON
                                bc.ID = bsCTE.ID
                    )

                    select * from (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By   @@version , CASE WHEN StatusID = 9 then 2 ELSE 1 END, CaseDeadline ASC, 
         SidstePeriodeSoegt) 
                        As rownum from ResultSelectorCTE where 1=1 AND StatusOwner <> 2 AND StatusOwner <> 3
                            AND SUBSTRING(CPR, 0, 3) BETWEEN 26-08-2014  AND 26-08-2015) As Result
                                where rownum Between ((1 - 1) * 100 + 1) AND (1 * 100);
```

Comment: Start by, as suggested, getting the execution plan. I also suggest you give some context like how long does it take, how many records does it obtain. At least take some time to format your code properly so people can read it easily, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [query execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan):

> The SQL Server Database Engine can display how it navigates tables and uses indexes to access or process the data for a query or other DML statement, such as an update. This is a display of an execution plan. To analyze a slow-running query, it is useful to examine the query execution plan to determine what is causing the problem.

Comment: I will definitely look into query execution plan. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything, start by losing the wildcards (*) sign. It's bad almost always as you are just saying, send everything and forgetting to actually review it.

Then, format your code correctly, CTE's are great, simplifies code, but it beats the purpose if your selects look like spaghetti, this has nothing to do with performance though.

Also, I had many times when UNION ALL outperformed UNION and I din't really think if duplicates were a problem or not, so you might want to look into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).

You didn't say if you are running it from Management Studio, are you on a local or remote server, how do the CTE's perform individually, etc. Context is king on this. 
Hope this helps.