# How to select table names with UNION results?

Tags: php, mysql

Here are the results with UNION, but I also want to know the source table associated with each row:

```
SELECT City FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

The actual result of the query is this:

> city
>   572
>   123

But I'd like this result instead:

> city tablet_result
>   572 Customers
>   123 Suppliers

Comment: just tack on a " ,'from_where' " as column 2 to each

Comment: could you explain more

Comment: duplicate http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/get-table-name-from-union-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try:

```
SELECT City,'Customers' as tblName FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City,'Suppliers' as tblName FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

Play with the order by.

Also consider doing a UNION ALL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49925) for the difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT City, 'Customers' as tablet_result FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City, 'Suppliers' as tablet_result FROM Suppliers
```