# Problems using UNION ALL

Tags: sql

I am using `union all` in my code something like

```
select * from country

union all 

select * from city
```

If same entry is there in both the select, then it should count only once.

Comment: [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: Usw `UNION` instead. It will eliminate duplicate rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION` instead:

```
select * from country

union 

select * from city
```

This will effectively filter out any duplicate records.

Comment: @Ritz Can your post some sample data demonstrating the issue?

Comment: i am not able to post my query

Comment: @Ritz I'm not asking you to post the query. I'm asking for some sample *data*, so that we can understand what the *real* issue is.

Comment: where i can post my query?

Comment: I have table called transaction, now i want to retrieve data from it and i have 2 condition 1> when trstype is 400 and trsdate is '27/04/2016' and 2> trstype is 600 and trsdate is '27/04/2016'. But some transaction on the same date is having trstype 400 and trstype 600 , but i want the queryu to count only once if it finds 400 it stops and search the different transaction

Comment: @Ritz Just edit the original post and add some data there along with the output the you get.

Comment: where status='a'
and trstypeid in(609)
and DepartmentAccountID in (30,31)
and (previousprocessid in ('3101'))
and NextProcessID=205
and trsdate between '2016-04-26 00:00:01' and '2016-04-26 23:59:59'

union all

where status='a'
and trstypeid in(1002)
and DepartmentAccountID in (30,31)
and (previousprocessid in (3101,3105))
and NextProcessID=205
and trsdate between '2016-04-26 00:00:01' and '2016-04-26 23:59:59'

it is giving me duplicate value for transaction having both trstypeid 609 and 1002 and i want it to populate once

Comment: @ritz: ***edit*** your question. Don't post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: i am using union all in my query and i want to remove the duplications

Comment: 72153615
72153615 i am getting 2 transaction id like this which i want to avoid

Comment: You can't get duplicates if you are using union. What you have might look like duplicates to you but it is not. You are missing something in your data. This is why people want you to show sample data, because then they can point at the two values of the rows that are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need duplicate you should use **union** not union all

```
select distinct * from country
union
select distinct * from city
```

**edit:**
You must be getting the duplicate values from **country** table.
Now I've changed my query according to your requirement

Comment: i've changed the query now try this @Ritz

Comment: Why do duplicate elimination twice? Wont change a thing.

Comment: @Ritz Now try the query

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't do `SELECT *` and **select only the columns you need**. UNION should remove duplicates.

```
      select col1, col2 from country
      union
      select col1, col2 from city
```

Comment: Why do duplicate elimination twice? Wont change a thing.

Comment: I said he doesn't need the group by because union will remove duplicates but maybe the group by can help the asker. In the example i wrote group by does nothing and CAN be removed