# Transpose multiple columns into one row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose, workbench

```
create table tab_1(
t1 decimal (10),
t2 decimal (10),
t3 decimal (10)
);

insert into tab_1(t1, t2, t3)
values(1,-2,-5);
insert into tab_1(t1, t2, t3)
values(-3,4,6);
insert into tab_1(t1, t2, t3)
values(5,1,2);

select @sum1:=sum(t1) FROM tab_1 WHERE t1 > 0
select @sum2:=sum(t2) FROM tab_1 WHERE t2 > 0
select @sum3:=sum(t3) FROM tab_1 WHERE t3 > 0

select @sum1, @sum2, @sum3;
```

Results:

```
 @sum1  @sum2 @sum3
 ------------------
  6      5      8
```

I have the query above and I want a query that transpose columns in one column and 3 rows, like below:

```
Sum
--
6
5
8
```

I use MySQL Workbench 6.3.7.

Comment: You're looking for what in SQL Server is the `UNPIVOT` function.  Unfortunately MySQL does have this capability out of the box, and I've been told that it gets very ugly, very fast.  For the simple example you gave, you could just `UNION` together the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t1 > 0 , t1, 0)) AS sum  FROM tab_1
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(IF(t2 > 0 , t2, 0)) AS sum  FROM tab_1
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(IF(t3 > 0 , t3, 0)) AS sum  FROM tab_1
```

<sub>[**UNION vs UNION ALL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)</sub>

**EDIT:**

In order to store the results in variables:  <sub>confused.why do you need this?</sub>

```
SET @sum1 := 0;
SET @sum2 := 0;
SET @sum3 := 0;
SELECT @sum1 := SUM(IF(t1 > 0 , t1, 0)) AS sum   FROM tab_1
UNION ALL
SELECT @sum2:= SUM(IF(t2 > 0 , t2, 0)) AS sum FROM tab_1
UNION ALL
SELECT @sum3 := SUM(IF(t3 > 0 , t3, 0)) AS sum  FROM tab_1;

SELECT @sum1,@sum2,@sum3;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works perfectly. But how i stock the results in a variable to use further ?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with your variable assignments.  Just put `union all` between them:

```
select 't1', sum(t1) FROM tab_1 WHERE t1 > 0
union all
select 't2', sum(t2) FROM tab_1 WHERE t2 > 0
union all
select 't3', sum(t3) FROM tab_1 WHERE t3 > 0;
```

(And I removed the variable assignment, because that doesn't seem necessary.)

I would include an identifier so I know which value corresponds to which column.