# SQL - Insert one column to another, without merging data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Searching the threads I could only find combining or merging, but not inserting and keeping original values.
So here is what I have:

```
ID time1 time2 time3
1   20    NULL  30
2   50    NULL  NULL
2   20    30    40
```

What I need is:

```
ID time
1   20
1   30
2   50
2   20
2   30
2   40
```

While ignoring Nulls.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the number of columns in the source table fixed?

Comment: Just a tip, in case you want to play with this later, add a column to the second table if you can, "timesource", populate with the source column

Comment: possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: @lalithkumar, sorry, I did not know about the UNION command. that is why I did not detect it.

Comment: No problem.check that link and learn more about it. @Johnny

Comment: @JohnHC Thanks, it was also in my mind too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with unpivot where it handles by default `NULL` value comparison and excludes those from result set.

**Reference purpose a temp table along with the sample data given in thread**

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 ID int,
 time1 int, time2 int, time3 int)

 INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, time1, time2,time3)
  VALUES (1,   20,    NULL,  30), 
  (2,   50,    NULL,  NULL), 
  (2,   20,    30,    40)
```

**Solution is here with the above temp table data**

```
  SELECT ID, [time]
  FROM #TempTable
  UNPIVOT
 (
  [time]
 for [timecolumnName] in (time1, time2,time3)
 ) unpiv;
```

Comment: Thanks! this one works great except I need also to remove duplicates, any idea how to do that? or should I just remove them with different command

Comment: I also would like to keep track on where the value came from (Time1,time2,time3)

Comment: SELECT ID, [time],[timecolumnName] 
  FROM #TempTable
  UNPIVOT
 (
  [time]
 for [timecolumnName] in (time1, time2,time3)
 ) unpiv; 

this will enable you tracking the column name

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, time1 as time from your_table where time1 is not null
union all 
select id, time2 from your_table where time2 is not null
union all 
select id, time3 from your_table where time3 is not null
```

Comment: For some reason it only gives me the time1 values, I'm currently trying to understand what's wrong because it's probably my fault

Comment: I didn't think it matters but I have two id's. so each id can have multiple rows depending on the second id. for now I only get the time1 column I have no idea why..

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have the three columns? If so just do;

```
INSERT [NewTable]
(Id, time)
SELECT Id, time1
FROM [OldTable]
WHERE time1 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT [NewTable]
(Id, time)
SELECT Id, time2
FROM [OldTable]
WHERE time2 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT [NewTable]
(Id, time)
SELECT Id, time3
FROM [OldTable]
WHERE time3 IS NOT NULL;
```

If you may have more than three let us know - you can still do this with Dynamic SQL