# Append 2 tables with identical fields

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with identical columns. Is there a way I can append them together. For example if my tables are:

Table 1:

```
ID  Age
 1   21
 2   26
 3   19
 4   40
```

Table 2:

```
ID  Age
 6   29
 8   40
10   35
```

I'd like the desired output to be:

```
ID  Age
 1   21
 2   26
 3   19
 4   40
 6   29
 8   40
10   35
```

Is there a way I can append these 2 tables. Being new to SQL I tried using insert but couldn't do much about it.

Would be great if some one can help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` query:

```
SELECT ID, Age
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Age
FROM table2
```

This will return all rows from each table in a single result. Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/667358).

Answer (score 0):

Use Union rather Union All if you want unique values based on two tables.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/2745294

```
SELECT ID, Age
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Age
FROM table2
```