# Use temp table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, temp-tables

I am trying to use use a temp table with SQLAlchemy and join it against an existing table. This is what I have so far

```
engine = db.get_engine(db.app, 'MY_DATABASE')
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "value": [100, 200, 300], "date": [date.today(), date.today(), date.today()]})
temp_table = db.Table('#temp_table',
                      db.Column('id', db.Integer),
                      db.Column('value', db.Integer),
                      db.Column('date', db.DateTime))
temp_table.create(engine)
df.to_sql(name='tempdb.dbo.#temp_table',
          con=engine,
          if_exists='append',
          index=False)
query = db.session.query(ExistingTable.id).join(temp_table, temp_table.c.id == ExistingTable.id)
out_df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, engine)
temp_table.drop(engine)
return out_df.to_dict('records')
```

This doesn't return any results because the insert statements that `to_sql` does don't get run (I think this is because they are run using `sp_prepexec`, but I'm not entirely sure about that).

I then tried just writing out the SQL statement (`CREATE TABLE #temp_table...`, `INSERT INTO #temp_table...`, `SELECT [id] FROM...`) and then running `pd.read_sql(query, engine)`. I get the error message

> This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

I guess this is because the statement does more than just `SELECT`?

How can I fix this issue (either solution would work, although the first would be preferable as it avoids hard-coded SQL). To be clear, I can't modify the schema in the existing database—it's a vendor database.

Comment: are there any records in `ExistingTable`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yeah. I actually changed it to a left join and added `temp_table.c.date` just to be sure. I get rows back with `None` in the `date` column.

Comment: why is your `date` column has type `DateTime` instead of `Date`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It's just some test code. The table has a datetime. I don't thin that should have any affect on the output though, do you?

Comment: i tested it on `sqlite` and it causes problems

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Ah. Feel free to change it to `Date`. Or whatever else works. The value doesn't actually matter. Not sure how sqllite handles temp tables though.

Comment: "I think this is because they are run using sp_prepexec"  This is plausible.  A temp table created in a stored procedure, including a call to sp_executesql, sp_prepexec, etc isnot the same as a temp table created in a top level batch, and will be destroyed automatically at the end of the call.

Comment: @KrisHarper: Why do you need to join on this temp table? Where does the data for this table come from? How many entries are usually there?

Comment: @van The data come from another database on another server. I need to incorporate that data into my query (specifically I need to use it in a `SUM` expression). It's not practical to pull all the data from `ExistingTable` and join in code because there may be several million records (but after aggregating those will be reduced to just a few records).

Comment: Check out this [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44270442/1422451) from an OP who had a similar pandas' `to_sql` and sqlalchemy issue, only for Postgres and not SQL Server where `to_sql` produced no error but no resulting table in dataframe push. OP even answered own question.

Comment: @KrisHarper: usually, how many records from that other database are used: several, dozens, hundreds, or more?

Comment: @van About 200. Although only a handful of those will match on the join condition.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In case the number of records to be inserted in the temporary table is small/moderate, one possibility would be to use a `literal subquery` or a `values CTE` instead of creating temporary table.

```
# MODEL
class ExistingTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'existing_table'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    # ...
```

Assume also following data is to be inserted into `temp` table:

```
# This data retrieved from another database and used for filtering
rows = [
    (1, 100, datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)),
    (3, 300, datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)),
    (5, 500, datetime.date(2017, 5, 1)),
]
```

Create a CTE or a sub-query containing that data:

```
stmts = [
    # @NOTE: optimization to reduce the size of the statement:
    # make type cast only for first row, for other rows DB engine will infer
    sa.select([
        sa.cast(sa.literal(i), sa.Integer).label("id"),
        sa.cast(sa.literal(v), sa.Integer).label("value"),
        sa.cast(sa.literal(d), sa.DateTime).label("date"),
    ]) if idx == 0 else
    sa.select([sa.literal(i), sa.literal(v), sa.literal(d)])  # no type cast

    for idx, (i, v, d) in enumerate(rows)
]
subquery = sa.union_all(*stmts)

# Choose one option below.
# I personally prefer B because one could reuse the CTE multiple times in the same query
# subquery = subquery.alias("temp_table")  # option A
subquery = subquery.cte(name="temp_table")  # option B
```

Create final query with the required joins and filters:

```
query = (
    session
    .query(ExistingTable.id)
    .join(subquery, subquery.c.id == ExistingTable.id)
    # .filter(subquery.c.date >= XXX_DATE)
)

# TEMP: Test result output
for res in query:
    print(res)
```

Finally, get pandas data frame:

```
out_df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, engine)
result = out_df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Ha, I was *just* thinking about doing this on my commute in this morning. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: and performance-wise, how good is this solution? Union all seems really heavy to me... Need to test it but it would be awesome if there is some kind thoughts about performance...

Comment: Why use UNION ALL?

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION` to avoid database engine eliminate duplicates as one could do that already in this code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/99594 for more information.
I do not think it is _heavy_ as the solution is explicitly for not overly large number of such records.

Comment: @van What would you consider to be a "small/moderate" number of records? I am interested in either a temp table (and COPY FROM using csv) or CTE to enable a complex insert of ~2,500 rows. INSERT INTO VALUES is painfully slow for this.

Comment: @freethebees, the best way for you is to profile the solution and see if it works. Also, since the answer was posted, sqalalchemy should have a more optimized way to insert multiple data with other constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use another solution - Process-Keyed Table

> A process-keyed table is simply a permanent table that serves as a
>   temp table. To permit processes to use the table simultaneously, the
>   table has an extra column to identify the process. The simplest way to
>   do this is the global variable @@spid (@@spid is the process id in SQL
>   Server).

...

> One alternative for the process-key is to use a GUID (data type
>   uniqueidentifier).

http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#prockeyed

Comment: Are you suggesting creating this table in tempdb? I think either way, it will run into the same issue that I am experiencing in the second part of my question where `read_sql` doesn't return any rows.

Comment: This table should be created in your db (`MY_DATABASE`), not a temp db. It's not a good, but it should work.

Comment: I don't have access to create tables in that database. It's a vendor database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [sqlalchemy `values` expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.values)? This is very simple, as stated in the documentation:

> ...The column expressions and the actual data for `Values` are given in two separate steps. The constructor receives the column expressions typically as `column()` constructs, and the data is then passed via the `Values.data()` method as a list, which can be called multiple times to add more data ...

The documentation provides also a nice example:

```
from sqlalchemy import column
from sqlalchemy import values

value_expr = values(
    column('id', Integer),
    column('name', String),
    name="my_values"
).data(
    [(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2'), (3, 'name3')]
)
```