# Writing dataframe to postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I want to write a pandas dataframe to a postgres table. I make a connection to db as follows:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

def connect(user, password, db, host='localhost', port=5432):
    '''Returns a connection and a metadata object'''
    url  = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format(user, password, host, port, db)

    # The return value of create_engine() is our connection object
    con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')

    # We then bind the connection to MetaData()
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=con, reflect=True)

    return con, meta

con, meta = connect('user_name', 'password', 'db_name', host='host_name')
```

When I read from a table that is already populated, it works fine:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM db.table_name limit 10",con=con)
print df
```

I would like to be able to write df to a table. To test this, I have a temporary table called 'test' with two fields name and age.

```
# create a temp df
table = [['name', 'age'], ['nameA' , 20], ['nameB', 30]]
headers = table.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
# write to db
df.to_sql('db.test', con, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
```

I then check if the temp table is populated:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM db.test limit 10",con=con)
print df
```

I get an empty dataframe! I got no errors when I use df.to_sql but nothing is getting written to the database (?). What am I missing and how do I go about fixing this?

Versions:

```
Pandas: 0.19.2
Sqlachemy: 1.1.10
Postgres: 9.4.9
```

Comment: Try not using period in table name.

Comment: @Parfait, can you please elaborate what you mean by that? Did you mean at the `db.test`? It is to point to the table called `test` under `db` schema.

Comment: But you connect to the *db* schema in connection engine. It is redundant and maybe affecting the table creation. Just reference *test*.

Comment: @Parfait tried that -- gives me an error about not finding `test`, does not complain if I do `db.test`.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for mentioning the table name -- that led me to look a little bit further into schema which led me to a solution. For those interested, check pd.io.sql.SQLDatabase(engine, meta=meta).

Comment: Do note: you can answer your own question especially to help future readers. Be sure to include the full solution with an explanation of what worked.

Answer (score 3):

I have not figured out why `df.to_sql` did not write to the table. Writing to table using `pd.io.sql.SQLDatabase` worked for my test case:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(con, schema='db_name')
meta.reflect()
pdsql = pd.io.sql.SQLDatabase(con, meta=meta)
pdsql.to_sql(df, 'test', if_exists='replace')
```

I would not consider this THE solution -- I'd be happy to accept better solution or an answer that brings a closure to why df.to_sql() does not behave as expected.