# Joining two select statements into one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How do I join these statements to return results together?

Query 1:

```
select scheduleentry.scheduledate,
    patientdemographics.accountnumber,
    patientdemographics.firstname,
    patientdemographics.middleinitial,
    patientdemographics.lastname,
    patientdemographics.address1,
    patientdemographics.address2,
    patientdemographics.city,
    patientdemographics.state,
    patientdemographics.zipcode,
    patientdemographics.dateofbirth,
    patientdemographics.sex,
    patientdemographics.hometelephone,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1name,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1policynumber,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1policygroupnumber,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorfirstname as insuredfirstname,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantormiddleinitial as insuredmiddleinitial,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorlastname as insuredlastname,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantoraddress1 as insuredaddress1,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantoraddress2 as insuredaddress2,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorcity as insuredcity,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorstate as insuredstate,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorzipcode as insuredzip,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantordateofbirth as insureddob,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantorsex as insuredsex,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1guarantortelephonenumber as insuredhomenumber,
    insurances.eligibilitypayornumber
from patientdemographics
inner join patientinsuranceprofiles
on  patientdemographics.accountnumber = patientinsuranceprofiles.patientaccountnumber
inner join scheduleentry
on  patientinsuranceprofiles.patientaccountnumber = scheduleentry.patientaccount
inner join insurances
on  patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance1mnemonic = insurances.mnemonic
where datediff(d, getdate(), scheduledate) = 1
    and patientinsuranceprofiles.activeflag = 1
order by scheduledate asc
```

Query 2:

```
select scheduleentry.scheduledate,
    patientdemographics.accountnumber,
    patientdemographics.firstname,
    patientdemographics.middleinitial,
    patientdemographics.lastname,
    patientdemographics.address1,
    patientdemographics.address2,
    patientdemographics.city,
    patientdemographics.state,
    patientdemographics.zipcode,
    patientdemographics.dateofbirth,
    patientdemographics.sex,
    patientdemographics.hometelephone,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2name,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2policynumber,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2policygroupnumber,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorfirstname as insuredfirstname,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantormiddleinitial as insuredmiddleinitial,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorlastname as insuredlastname,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantoraddress1 as insuredaddress1,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantoraddress2 as insuredaddress2,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorcity as insuredcity,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorstate as insuredstate,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorzipcode as insuredzip,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantordateofbirth as insureddob,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantorsex as insuredsex,
    patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2guarantortelephonenumber as insuredhomenumber,
    insurances.eligibilitypayornumber
from patientdemographics
inner join patientinsuranceprofiles
on  patientdemographics.accountnumber = patientinsuranceprofiles.patientaccountnumber
inner join scheduleentry
on  patientinsuranceprofiles.patientaccountnumber = scheduleentry.patientaccount
inner join insurances
on  patientinsuranceprofiles.insurance2mnemonic = insurances.mnemonic
where datediff(d, getdate(), scheduledate) = 1
    and patientinsuranceprofiles.activeflag = 1
order by scheduledate asc
```

Comment: `union all` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use UNION ALL approach as others suggested.

```
(Query 1)
union all
(Query 2)
```

For your case, perhaps case and little modification to the join condition will work. Please try the below:

```
select se.scheduledate,
    pd.accountnumber,
    pd.firstname,
    pd.middleinitial,
    pd.lastname,
    pd.address1,
    pd.address2,
    pd.city,
    pd.state,
    pd.zipcode,
    pd.dateofbirth,
    pd.sex,
    pd.hometelephone,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1name                     else pip.insurance2name end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1policynumber             else pip.insurance2policynumber end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1policygroupnumber        else pip.insurance2policygroupnumber end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorfirstname       else pip.insurance2guarantorfirstname as insuredfirstname end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantormiddleinitial   else pip.insurance2guarantormiddleinitial as insuredmiddleinitial end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorlastname        else pip.insurance2guarantorlastname as insuredlastname end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantoraddress1        else pip.insurance2guarantoraddress1 as insuredaddress1 end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantoraddress2        else pip.insurance2guarantoraddress2 as insuredaddress2 end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorcity            else pip.insurance2guarantorcity as insuredcity end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorstate           else pip.insurance2guarantorstate as insuredstate end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorzipcode         else pip.insurance2guarantorzipcode as insuredzip end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantordateofbirth     else pip.insurance2guarantordateofbirth as insureddob end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantorsex             else pip.insurance2guarantorsex as insuredsex end,
    case when i.mnemonic = pip.insurance1mnemonic then pip.insurance1guarantortelephonenumber else pip.insurance2guarantortelephonenumber as insuredhomenumber end,
    i.eligibilitypayornumber
from patientdemographics pd
inner join patientinsuranceprofiles pip
on  pd.accountnumber = pip.patientaccountnumber
inner join scheduleentry se
on  pip.patientaccountnumber = se.patientaccount
inner join insurances i
on  i.mnemonic in (pip.insurance1mnemonic, pip.insurance2mnemonic)
where datediff(d, getdate(), scheduledate) = 1
    and pip.activeflag = 1
order by scheduledate asc
```

Comment: #GurV Tried that. Getting a Incorrect syntax near Union

Comment: @JohnMolina take the order by of the query you are running first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION ALL` in between the two queries e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE...

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
FROM ....
WHERE...
```

You can read about the differences in `UNION` and `UNION ALL` here: [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

You could also use CTE - if there is a column you can join on, e.g.

```
;WITH Query1 AS
(
 SELECT Column1
 FROM ...
)
,Query2 AS
( 
 SELECT Column1
 FROM ...
)
SELECT     *
FROM       Query1 AS Q1
INNER JOIN Query2 AS Q2 ON Q1.Column1 = Q2.Column1
```