# SQL Server : Membership Renewals

Tags: sql-server

I am new to this website but I've referenced this website a lot in the past to guide me along my current class.

Our teacher assigned us some homework and we created a database that has online seminars. The members in the database pay for the online seminars. They can pay in either 4 different ways: Monthly, quarterly, yearly, or every 2 years. I created a renewal table that assigns a RenewalID for each of the subscription levels and is used as a foreign key in the Members table to indicate their level of subscription.

Here's the question that the teacher is asking:

> Members are charged for renewals according to their payment plan (monthly, quarterly, etc..) on the anniversary of the date they joined. A user who joined on the 7th should always be billed on the 7th, whether it's every one, three or 12 months. Some method is needed to scan for current members who are up for renewal and to initiate the billing to their credit card.

I was thinking to create a view that would display their card information when it's time to bill to them. I couldn't figure out the monthly, quarterly, or 2 year cycles but I used the following to calculate the yearly renewal:

```
select pc.* 
from Members m
inner join paymentcard pc on pc.memberid = m.MemberID
where 
    CurrentFlag <> 0 
    and DATEPART(month, startdate) = DATEPART(MONTH, getdate()) 
    and datepart(day, startdate) = DATEPART(day, getdate()) 
    and RenewalID = 2
```

However, after messing around more, I'm beginning to realize that it's going to be more than just a view. I believe it needs to be a stored procedure. I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing this..

I'm turning to the wonderful members of this website to help me figure this out.. thanks!

Comment: just do a union of the 3 renewal type queries if you want it to be most readable...or it could be done in a single query...you shouldn't need a complex procedure to do it

Comment: +1 for being up front about the fact that this is a homework question, and showing the effort put in prior to posting the question. As far as solutions, I’d agree with @Ctznkane525 that you only need to [`union all`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49925/960362) the queries together, to create one result set from multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out with another student. This is what we came up with. Also, the teacher said this works so I'm content.

I understand how useful this website is so I will post the solution I found and also the solution my instructor came up with to help anyone in the future.

**My solution:**

First, I created the view:

```
    GO
    CREATE VIEW vwRenewal
    AS
    select m.memberid, m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.StartDate, m.RenewalID, r.RenewalPrice, pc.CardID
    from Members m
    inner join
    Renewal r
    on m.RenewalID = r.RenewalID
    inner join
    PaymentCard pc
    on pc.MemberID = m.MemberID
    WHERE m.CurrentFlag <> 0 AND m.RenewalID = 4
        AND DATEPART(day, startdate) = DATEPART(day, getdate())

        UNION ALL
    select m.memberid, m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.StartDate, m.RenewalID, r.RenewalPrice, pc.CardID
    from Members m
    inner join
    Renewal r
    on m.RenewalID = r.RenewalID
    inner join
    PaymentCard pc
    on pc.MemberID = m.MemberID
    WHERE m.CurrentFlag <> 0 AND m.RenewalID = 3
        AND DATEPART(day, startdate) = DATEPART(day, getdate())
        AND DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) IN
            ((select (datepart(month, m.startdate) + 3)),
            (select (datepart(month, m.startdate) + 6)),
            (select (datepart(month, m.startdate) + 9)))
    UNION ALL

    select m.memberid, m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.StartDate, m.RenewalID, r.RenewalPrice, pc.CardID
    from Members m
    inner join
    Renewal r
    on m.RenewalID = r.RenewalID
    inner join
    PaymentCard pc
    on pc.MemberID = m.MemberID
    WHERE m.CurrentFlag <> 0 AND m.RenewalID = 2
        AND DATEPART(day, startdate) = DATEPART(day, getdate())
        AND DATEPART(month, startdate) = DATEPART(month, getdate())
    UNION 
    ALL
    select m.memberid, m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.StartDate, m.RenewalID, r.RenewalPrice, pc.CardID
    from Members m
    inner join
    Renewal r
    on m.RenewalID = r.RenewalID
    inner join
    PaymentCard pc
    on pc.MemberID = m.MemberID
    WHERE m.CurrentFlag <> 0 AND m.RenewalID = 1
        AND GETDATE() IN
        ((SELECT dateadd(month, 24, m.startdate)),
        (select dateadd(month, 48, m.startdate)),
        (select dateadd(month, 72, m.startdate)))
    GO
```

Then, the stored procedure:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Renewal
>
> AS    BEGIN
>
>   IF EXISTS (select * from vwRenewal)             BEGIN
>           INSERT INTO Transactions (CardID, TransactionDate, Charge, Result)
>               VALUES (        (select CardID
>                                   from vwRenewal),
>                                       getdate(),
>                                           (select RenewalPrice
>                                               from vwRenewal),
>                                                   'Pending')
>           END     SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE Result = 'Pending'
>
> END
> ```

**Instructor solution:**

```
        -- Determine the member's next charge date based on the last time they were charged.

        DECLARE @RETURNDATE DATE        -- Return value
        DECLARE @SUBLEVEL INT           -- Member's subscription level
        DECLARE @MEMBERDAYS INT         -- Days in member subscription period
        DECLARE @JOINDATE DATE          -- Date member joined
        DECLARE @LASTCHARGE DATE        -- Last charge to member account

        -- Get subscription level and days in subscription period.
        SELECT @SUBLEVEL = m.SubscriptionLevel, @MEMBERDAYS = s.DaysPerPeriod, @JOINDATE = m.JoinDate
        FROM Members m
        INNER JOIN SubscriptionLevels s
        ON s.SubLevelID = m.SubscriptionLevel
        WHERE MemberID = @MemberID

        -- If the member's subscription level is not free...
        IF @SUBLEVEL NOT IN (SELECT SubLevelID FROM SubscriptionLevels WHERE RenewalAmt > 0)
        BEGIN

            -- Get the most recent account charge date for the member.
            -- There should always be a charge date, even for new members.
            SELECT TOP 1 @LASTCHARGE = ChargeDate
            FROM AccountCharges
            WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
            ORDER BY ChargeDate DESC

            -- If there is a charge date, add the number of days in the membership period
            -- to get the new date. Otherwise, add it to the join date. 
            IF @LASTCHARGE IS NOT NULL
                SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @MEMBERDAYS, @LASTCHARGE)
            ELSE
                SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(DAY, @MEMBERDAYS, @JOINDATE) -- Just in case there's no previous charge.

        END
        ELSE
            -- If the member has a free plan, just add one year to today so the member is never charged.
            SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())

        RETURN @RETURNDATE

        END

        GO
```

Note: I only post this to help people in the future in some way who may encounter a similar situation as me or whatever they need it for.. 
Hope this helps. Enjoy.
Like any code, this is only a couple ways to accomplish this task. There are many other ways I'm sure..