# MySQL Union Returns Inconsistent Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a UNION statement to combine scores for students from two different tables (MySQL 5.6).  It is returning inconsistent results.  When I run each statement independently, they generate the right results for all students.  When I combine them with the UNION, it is correct for all but one student.

Even stranger, if I remove any one of the items being added from the first query, it sums correctly for ALL records.

For instance, removing `sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.pre_req_points,0))` or `sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.bonus_points,0))` from the query causes it to return correct results for all students.

```
select first_name, last_name, location, sum(total_points) as total_points from (
select first_name, last_name, location, (
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.pre_req_points,0)) + 
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.bonus_points,0)) +
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.a_points,0))) AS total_points
from products, students_products, students
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ea891/1

Student A works correctly but Student B does not.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use union all, try below query and it's better if you use explicit join

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ea891/7

```
select first_name, last_name, location, sum(total_points)
from
(
select first_name, last_name, location, (
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.pre_req_points,0)) + 
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.bonus_points,0)) +
                sum(ifnull(owl_tracker.a_points,0))) AS total_points
from products left join students_products on products.product_id = students_products.product_id
left join students on students_products.student_id = students.unique_id
left join  owl_tracker on students.unique_id = owl_tracker.student_id
where products.product_type in ('Group_Course','Full_Course') and products.test_date_id = '19' and unique_id in ('4833' ,'4956')
group by first_name, last_name, location

union all        

        select first_name, last_name, location, 
                sum(ifnull(owl.points,0)) AS total_points
from products left join students_products on 
products.product_id = students_products.product_id
left join students on students_products.student_id = students.unique_id
left join owl on students.unique_id = owl.student_id 
where products.product_type  In ('Group_Course' ,'Full_Course') and
        products.test_date_id = '19' and
        unique_id in( '4833' , '4956')
        group by first_name, last_name, location) t_union
        group by first_name, last_name, location
        order by  location, last_name
```

Comment: This makes sense now - both select queries happened to return the same number of points for that student, so it did a distinct.  Using the UNION ALL fixes the issue.  I'll also make changes to the join structure.

Answer (score 1):

By default, UNION is UNION DISTINCT, which means that any duplicated row will be filtered out in the subquery. Change that to UNION ALL. See [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)