# How null values are treated in union/union all in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, sql-null

Based on below statement

```
select null
union
select null
```

the output of the above statement is:

```
null
```

While this statement :

```
select null
union all
select null
```

Outputs:

```
null
null
```

As `null <> null` then how the value null is treated here and in which datatype it is considered?

Comment: `DISTINCT`, `UNION` and `GROUP BY` use the same semantics as`is not distinct from` when it comes to NULL equality

Comment: In SQL Server that would be `int`. I don't know if that is the same in MySql . If you CREATE TABLE AS SELECT what datatype do you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Answer (score 5):

In SQL:

- `UNION` is a set operator and involves checking for (and suppressing) *duplicate rows*
- Duplicate rows are defined as *not being distinct*
- Distinct (values or rows) is defined as:

> **Two values are said to be not distinct if either: both are the null value**, or they compare equal according to Subclause 8.2,
> "<comparison predicate>". Otherwise they are distinct. Two rows
> (or partial rows) are distinct if at least one of their pairs of
> respective values is distinct. Otherwise they are not distinct. The
> result of evaluating whether or not two values or two rows are
> distinct is never unknown.

(the above is an excerpt from SQL-92 specs, emphasis mine). So, in this example:

```sql
select null
union all
select null
```

the two rows are considered duplicates of each other because the null values in first column are considered not distinct... i.e. same. And by definition `UNION` returns only one row from a set of duplicate rows.

Answer (score 4):

In standard SQL, `UNION` removes duplicate records, `UNION ALL` does not. Happlily your RDBMS is clever enough to figure out that `NULL IS NULL`, and eliminates duplicate rows when `UNION` is used.

NB : `null = null` is `unknown`, however `null <> null` is `unknown` as well. The only way to check for nullity is to use something like `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT case when null <> null then 1 else 0 end;  --> yields : 0
SELECT case when null =  null then 1 else 0 end;  --> yields : 0
SELECT case when null IS null then 1 else 0 end;  --> yields : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you know the difference between UNION (deduplicates results) and UNION ALL

```
select 'x' from dual where null is null \\results with x
```

In this case null is actually null. Which means union returns correct result (deduplicated)