# How to insert data from multi tables to one table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I'd a trouble with inserting data from 3 table: 
A (id, name), B (id, name), C (id, name). They have the same field like that.
How can I insert data from 3 tables above into table D (id, name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT INTO table_d(id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM table_a
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name
FROM table_b
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name
FROM table_c;
```

If you want to remove duplicate rows in 3 tables, change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`. Refer information about [union vs union all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: You're missing one UNION (ALL) for table_c (and didn't say when to use UNION, and when UNION ALL).