# multiple table joined by union not giving exact result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many tables in my inventory system like product sale, product purchase, employee salary, office/shop expense.
now I want to show all the table activity in a single table. so what I did is used the union query, so that, I can print all the other table activity in a table format. which I am naming as a Cash_Report, like shop Tally book.

```
 SELECT `selldate`, `customerid`, `payment_taka`, `token` FROM `sell` WHERE `token` = 's_Cash'
 UNION
 SELECT `recievedate`, `cusotmer_id`, `amounts`, `bycashcheque` FROM `recevecollection` WHERE `bycashcheque` = 'rac_Cash' 
UNION 
SELECT `pay_date`, `sup_id`, `amnts`, `status` FROM `supplierpayment` WHERE `status`='pts_Cash' 
UNION 
SELECT `expiredate`, `customerid`, `amount`, `fromtable` FROM `cheque` WHERE `approve`='1' .....and goes on and on.
```

now the main issue is I have got What I wanted to make happen. but suddenly I have noticed a problem. 
from the `sell` table all the database entries are not being fetched. But when I run the exact same query on `sell` table it works perfectly. I just wanted to know what went wrong with union, I tried this code with `union all` though, but nothing seems to work for this case.

**A recommendation** 
I was just wondering if anyone can tell how this job is done. how to bring all the tables together and show them in a single table by query. I just to know the procedure.

[image]

Result with union query
[image]

image without `union`

As I have mentioned with the red mark on the picture that with `union` query i get 12 rows where it should come 16 rows.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: how people can know what is your expected result if you not share , so for getting help you have to share your sample data and expected output

Comment: sir, result added. please check it out

Comment: Do your data set have duplicate values? You should look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53721250/4959470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names in the result-set are usually equal to the column names in the first SELECT statement in the UNION.

The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use `UNION ALL`

Check the following links

UNION ALL

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union_all

UINON

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union

Comment: thanks, It worked for me. I just forgot to see the other side theory. My bad.

Comment: Sounds great, Happy coding