# How to compare two sets of rows in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So, the problem is that i have two results (eg. number):

RES1:
10
11

RES2:
10
13

I need to compare those like if RES1 in RES2 and RES2 in RES1.

I would like to have result like:

RES3:
11
13

How do i do that?

I tried

RES1 MINUS RES2 
UNION
RES2 MINUS RES1

but this approach is very slow, becouse my table contains milions of rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use one of supplied packages. [DBMS_COMPARISON](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS868)
The Package allows to compare and sync tables. It's only required that tables have an index.

1) create diff datasets

```
create table to_compare2 as (select OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_TYPE, case when mod(object_id,18) = 0 then  CREATED +1 else CREATED end  CREATED  from all_objects where mod(object_id,6) = 0 );
CREATE table to_compare1 as (SELECT OBJECT_NAME, SUBOBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_TYPE, case when mod(object_id,12) = 0 then  CREATED +1 else CREATED end  CREATED  FROM ALL_OBJECTS where mod(object_id,3) = 0 );
```

2) create indexes.

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX to_compare1_idx  on  to_compare1(object_id);
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX to_compare2_idx  on  to_compare2(object_id);
```

3) Prepare comparision context

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_COMPARISON.create_comparison (
    comparison_name    => 'MY_COMPARISION',
    schema_name        => user,
    object_name        => 'to_compare1',
    dblink_name        => NULL,
    remote_schema_name => null,
    remote_object_name => 'to_compare2');
END;
/
```

4) Execute comparison and check results.

```
DECLARE
  v_scan_info  DBMS_COMPARISON.comparison_type;
  v_result     BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_result := DBMS_COMPARISON.compare (
                comparison_name => 'MY_COMPARISION',
                scan_info       => v_scan_info,
                perform_row_dif => TRUE
              );

  IF NOT v_result THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Differences. scan_id=' || v_scan_info.scan_id);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('No differences.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

4) Results

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_comparison_row_dif
WHERE  comparison_name = 'MY_COMPARISION';
```

if `local_rowid` is not null and `remote_rowid` is null -> record exit in table_1
if `local_rowid` is  null and `remote_rowid is` not null -> record exit in table_2
if `local_rowid` is not  null and `remote_rowid` is not null -> record exist in both tables but it has different values

Answer (score 0):

**solutin 1:**

try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

why `UNION ALL` is better then `UNION` you can read here: [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

**solutin 2:**

you can try to use `full outer join`

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id)
from a
full outer join b on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null
or b.id is null
```

Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88f81/3

Comment: Well, i can try full outer join but i'll kill db (milions of rows). Am i right?

Comment: i don't know, you should try it out. it is just a way you can do it. There is no general solution that always will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are those Values unique in RES1 or RES2? Then you could try counting:

```
SELECT col
FROM (
    SELECT col FROM RES1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col FROM RES2
)
GROUP BY col
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

If it is not unique, you'd have to add a distinct on both sides of the union, which makes it a lot slower