# Join two tables without getting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two Tables in SQL:

```
Table 1                        Table 2
A B C                          A B C
0 2 3                          1 3 5  
3 4 5                          4 6 7 
1 6 8                          3 4 5
```

I want to "merge" them. The result should look like this.

```
Table Result
A B C
0 2 3
3 4 5
1 6 8
1 3 5
4 6 7
```

So I just want to take over the rows in Table 2 which are not in Table 1. I dont want the rows in Table 2 which are already in Table 1. As you can see the name of the columns are also the same.

Comment: Seem like you're looking for `UNION`. What is your expected result if table1 has 3 duplicated rows, table2 has 5 duplicated rows that's the same as in table1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Table1
Union
select * from Table2
```

If you want to Insert into new Table Then

```
Select * 
INTO Table3
FROM
(select * from Table1
Union
select * from Table2)
```

Comment: How can I combine this with a Into statement to save it in a new Table?

Comment: i have updated answer for your solution please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all

```
select * from Table1
Union all
select * from Table2
```

Comment: Is it that simple? Now I feel dumb because I wasted your time with such a simple Question. But thank you very much ! :)

Comment: `UNION ALL` takes duplicates.

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon as it is possible

Comment: @ProgrammJüngling02 If combination is same in both the table and you want only 1 then use Union else use union all

Comment: @ProgrammJüngling02 Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all