# separating information based on weekends and weekdays in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to get the following output

| enrollment_month | weekend_revenue | weekday_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jun | 550 | 790 |
| may | 1570 | 2020 |

this is the code I have:

```
select g.enrollment_month, sum(g.total_revenue) as weekday_revenue 
from gracieMusicFact g
where g.lesson_day in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
group by enrollment_month;

select g.enrollment_month, sum(g.total_revenue) as weekend_revenue 
from gracieMusicFact g
where g.lesson_day in ('Saturday','Sunday')
group by enrollment_month;
```

Union only gives me either one of the weekend_revenue or weekday_revenue. How do I make two different select statements with different criteria?

Thanks

**Edit**: Using union all gives me this outpu:

```
| enrollment_month   | weekday_revenue |

| jun|  790 |
| may| 2020 |
| jun|  550 |
| may| 1570 |
```

Comment: You can join both the select statements based on the `enrollment_month`

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select g.enrollment_month,
       sum(case when g.lesson_day in ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') then g.total_revenue else 0 end) as weekday_revenue,
       sum(case when g.lesson_day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then g.total_revenue else 0 end) as weekend_revenue
from gracieMusicFact g
group by enrollment_month;
```

Comment: omg you're a legend - this works perfectly! thankyou!

Comment: `not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')` or `not like 'S%'` would be less to type than `in ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use UNION ALL

The only difference between Union and Union All is that Union All will not removes duplicate rows or records, instead, it just selects all the rows from all the tables which meets the conditions of your specifics query and combines them into the result table. ... Whereas, UNION ALL works with all data type columns.

[What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: unfortunately union all doesnt work. I'll edit my post to show what it does. Thanks for your reply tho!