# how to properly use where clause in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT supplierid, SUM(price) 
FROM Products 
GROUP BY supplierid  
ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC 
WHERE SUM(price) > 200;
```

WHERE clause keeps me stuck

Comment: `WHERE` comes before `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`. [Here's the relevant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html); note that the order is `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Where appears before group by - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all you are probably looking for group by...having

Answer (score 1):

for aggregation function applied  to distinct values you need a proper group by clause and use HAVING  (not where) for filter aggregated  result

```
SELECT supplierid, SUM(price) 
FROM Products 
GROUP BY supplierid  
HAVING SUM(price) > 200
ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A `WHERE` clause is used to define scalar filtering predicates on a query and can only be placed following the `FROM` - and any `JOIN`s - and before any grouping, aggregating, or ordering clauses.

As the `WHERE` may only contain scalar predicates, it can not contain any aggregate functions such as (non-exhaustive) `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, or `MAX`.

The example provided in the question is invalid syntax, and contains no valid predicates for use in a `WHERE` clause.