# Need a script which will compare a particular static table present in Main Site and DR Site

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot

Need a script which will compare a particular static table "T_HANDLING" present in Main Site and DR Site. so this script should tell whether the table data is in synch or not between main and DR database.

This can be a script or springboot service as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I use:

```
select count(*) as MISMATCHED
  from (select * from PRIMARY_TABLE minus select * from BACKUP_TABLE)
union
select count(*) as MISMATCHED
  from (select * from BACKUP_TABLE minus select * from PRIMARY_TABLE);
```

Counts will be zero when the tables are not mismatched.

Comment: I would use UNION ALL rather than UNION, and/or include a literal in each projection to distinguish the two counts. It will occasionally be informative to know which site is lacking records, and it will never harmful to include such a label.

Comment: Thanks lightkeeper and APC for your answers. But in a SQL developer when i have 2 connections how can I execute this script when the backup table is from another connection or database ?

Comment: Can you use the [Database Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm)?

Comment: My real script does include literals for identification. I compare a large number of tables, but just wanted to present something simple. My databases are on two different boxes, and I use DBLink to communicate between the two instances. Why use UNION ALL instead of UNION?

Comment: @lightkeeper Performance. [what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)