# joining two tables with different columns into one

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have 2 tables that I want to join. They both have a uuid field and a text name field. Besides that they have no connection, The end result I wish to achieve is one table that combined all names and all uuid fields.

```
SELECT tbl1.uuid as uuid, 
       tbl1.nname as tname, 
       tbl2.uuid as uuid, 
       tble2.zname as tname 
FROM some_table_1 tbl1 
CROSS JOIN some_table_2 tbl2
```

the query above creates 2 uuid columns and 2 name columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UNION` operator. With `UNION ALL` every row from both tables are in the result set. If you use `UNION` only distinct rows will be in the result set.

```
SELECT uuid, nname as tname FROM some_table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT uuid, zname as tname FROM some_table_2
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/9393458) about a good explanation of `UNION`.

Comment: Does this create a new table?

Comment: @HashimAziz: No, this is just the "concatenation" of two select statements. What makes you think, this coudl create a new table? But you can create a new table and fill it directly with something like ```CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT * FROM OldTable```. See the mysql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)