# How to merge these queries and create a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these three working queries:

```
SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' 
  AND a = 'LK0601' 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

```
SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' 
  AND a = 'DT9834'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

```
SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' 
  AND a = 'LM3526' 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In these queries, I get the latest entry for the different values of a.

How can I merge them into one query?

So that it becomes something like the following:

```
SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' 
  AND a IN ('LM3526','DT9834','LK0601') 
GROUP BY a 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

From the above query, I want to get the latest rows for all the different values of `a`.

I am using the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Select only the  database that you are working with `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` are not the same.

Comment: I know that is beside the point, but why do people so often ask to "merge several queries into one"? What is the point?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've to get this data for over 10000 values of `a`. And querying DB one time is better than doing it 10000 times.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , what CoolBreeze said has often been also my personal opinion-based assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a, time, b, c
FROM table_first
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' AND
      a IN ('LK0601', 'DT9834', 'LM3526')
ORDER BY a, time DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the results using UNION:

```
(SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' AND a = 'LK0601' 
ORDER BY time desc limit 1)

UNION

(SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' AND a = 'DT9834' 
ORDER BY time desc limit 1)

UNION

(SELECT a, time, b, c 
FROM table_first 
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2022-02-13 00:00:00' AND a = 'LM3526' 
ORDER BY time desc limit 1);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=57944d198b94e56723344ee464c2d746)

This query will have the correct result, but will cost some more resources as the accepted answer, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fe7cdfc0cda7c877585459406911d6e0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Luuk. And for the Fiddles. As far as I remember, I have seen very many `Union All` Answers in the Community places, and almost no `Union` w/o "All" suggestions in general. This one also looks interesting in that context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: In this case the result will never be the "same" because `a` is always different.  I also could have use `UNION ALL`, which  might cost less (but this is a bad example to take that decision from, because not enough records...

Comment: Yes, there was no criticism intended in my previous comment, BTW, I found your input rather interesting, not necessarily debatable :)

Comment: No worries, it was not receive as criticism! , In fact a good question is it always to know if one should use `UNION` of `UNION ALL`, while most people do `UNION ALL` buy default, and only when needed delete the `ALL`