# How to put the result of two different columns with same data type within one column such that both rows from both tables are unique in target table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example I have two columns:

```
Column A: dog, cat, mouse

Column B: truck, jeep, lorry
```

I want a situation where:

```
Column C : dog, truck, cat, jeep, mouse, lorry
```

I am using Snowflake

Comment: Maybe a UNION query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake query performance with UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72244931/snowflake-query-performance-with-union)

Comment: I tried UNION but got an error: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Should edit question to show your attempted SQL. Better to show data as a table, not just lines that look like array or CSV string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that columns colA, colB are strings, the values should be first splitted to atomic values SPLIT_TO_TABLE and combined again LISTAGG:

```
SELECT ID, COLA, COLB, LISTAGG(COL, ', ') AS colC
FROM (
  SELECT ID, COLA, COLB, TRIM(s1.VALUE::STRING) AS col
  FROM tab
  ,TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(tab.colA, ',')) AS s1
  UNION
  SELECT ID, COLA, COLB, TRIM(s2.VALUE::STRING) AS col
  FROM tab
  ,TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(tab.colB, ',')) AS s2
) AS sub
GROUP BY ID, COLA, COLB
ORDER BY ID;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 1 AS id, 'dog, cat, mouse' AS colA, 'truck, jeep, lorry' AS colB UNION 
SELECT 2 AS id, 'sparrow' AS colA, 'sparrow, parrot' AS colB;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Sidenote: For storing non-atomic values ARRAY is a better choice:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 1 AS id, ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'] AS colA, ['truck', 'jeep', 'lorry'] AS colB UNION 
SELECT 2 AS id, ['sparrow'] AS colA, ['sparrow', 'parrot'] AS colB;
```

[image]

Then combining is a matter of using [ARRAY_UNION_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_union_agg.html):

```
SELECT ID, ARRAY_UNION_AGG(COL) AS COLC
FROM (
  SELECT ID, COLA AS col FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, COLB AS col FROM tab
) sub
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would prefer it not be an array. Both columns have individual rows.  I would prefer a situation where : rows in column A come first on top in Column C, then rows in column B come second below in Column C or vice versa, OR any iteration or mixture of rows from column a and b being present in Column C , one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Consider a UNION query:

```
SELECT 1 AS GrpID, FieldA AS Data FROM tablename
UNION SELECT 2, FieldB FROM tablename;
```