# SELECT Table Based on Condition From Multi tables using UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following four tables:

**Produit**

| id | Produit | Unit | Quantité | Date_S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | torada55 | 904 | 32 | 08/06/2022 |
| 2 | teska | 560 EHRS | 44 | 08/06/2022 |
| 3 | shella | 905 | 56 | 08/06/2022 |
| 4 | teska | 701 | 12 | 08/06/2022 |
| 5 | teska | BNA | 45 | 08/06/2022 |

**Aéro**

| id | Unit | region | Division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 560 EHRS | FMC | DNB |
| 14 | 428 EHAC | FMO | DTM |

**Commun**

| id | Unit | region | Division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | BNA | FMC | DKM |
| 14 | BMEK | FMO | DE |

**Flot**

| id | Unit | region | Division | Type_Equip | Equip | Prod_Util | Périod_Vidange | Q_vid_equi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 904 | FMC | DNBLS | MOTEUR&DG | Moteur diesel | SHELL | 15 | 12 |
| 23 | 905 | FME | DNBLS | MOTEUR&DG | Moteur diesel | SHELL | 15 | 12 |
| 22 | 906 | FMO | DNBLS | MOTEUR&DG | Moteur diesel | SHELL | 15 | 12 |
| 21 | 911 | FME | DNBLS | MOTEUR&DG | Moteur diesel | SHELL | 15 | 12 |
| 55 | 701 | FME | DNBLS | MOTEUR&DG | Moteur diesel | SHELL | 15 | 12 |

**Expected Output**

| id | Produit | Unit | Quantité | Date_S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | torada55 | 904 | 32 | 08/06/2022 |
| 2 | teska | 560 EHRS | 44 | 08/06/2022 |
| 5 | teska | BNA | 45 | 08/06/2022 |

I've tried this Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Produit,
     Aéro 
WHERE Aéro.Unit = Produit.Unit 
  AND Aéro.region = 'FMC' 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM Produit,
     Commun 
WHERE Commun.Unit = Produit.Unit 
  AND Commun.region = 'FMC' 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM Produit,
     Flot 
WHERE Flot.Unit = Produit.Unit 
  AND Flot.region = 'FMC'
```

While I select "*Produit*" Based on just the "*Commun*" and "*Aéro*" tables, it works just fine. If I select just "*Produit*" based on "*Flot*" table, it's work too. But when I select "*Produit*" based on the other three tables, it returns error.

Comment: Try explicit column names/types that would match among the three `Union` parts, like for example `Select col1, col2, col3 ....From ...` And better use the newer `Join` syntax to describe the relations https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract all products whose unit is associated to the region "FMC", you can apply the `UNION ALL` on the units from your three filtering tables ("*Aéro*", "*Commun*" and "*Flot*"), then select all those products that allow that unit in the corresponding "*Produit.Unit*".

```
SELECT * 
FROM Produit 
WHERE Unit IN (SELECT Unit FROM Aéro   WHERE region = 'FMC'
               UNION ALL 
               SELECT Unit FROM Commun WHERE region = 'FMC'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT Unit FROM Flot   WHERE region = 'FMC')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6AYL94oYsmGWNwi5jUUFEj/0).

**Note**: `UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION` because it avoids you a heavy aggregation. Check the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).