# Sqlite unexpected removal of duplicate when using union

Tags: sqlite, duplicates, union, gnucash

I am using sqlite on a GnuCash database, and my query is unexpectedly removing an identical result row when a `union` statement is present.

The row in question looks like this (with the name changed, since this comes from donor data):

`2023-02-14 10:59:00, ACH, Name Changed, , 20000, 100, General Fund, 1010-000`

The query should be returning two identical rows like this, because this particular donor made two identical donations on the same day.

Without the `union` statement, the query looks like this:

```
-- Generate donor transactions
    -- Transactions without fees:
    select date, num, description, notes, numer, denom, fund, code from
        -- Pull most of the data from the split for account 4010-000
        (select
            transactions.post_date as date,
            transactions.num as num,
            transactions.description as description,
            memo as notes,
            transactions.guid as guid
            from ((splits
            inner join accounts on splits.account_guid = accounts.guid)
            inner join transactions on splits.tx_guid = transactions.guid)
            where accounts.code = "4010-000") a
    left join
        -- Pull the fund from the split for one of the 1010% accounts
        (select
            accounts.description as fund,
            accounts.code as code,
            value_num as numer,
            value_denom as denom,
            transactions.guid as guid
            from ((splits
            inner join accounts on splits.account_guid = accounts.guid)
            inner join (select * from transactions where not exists
                (select 1 from splits inner join accounts on splits.account_guid = accounts.guid
                where accounts.code = "8190-000" and splits.tx_guid = transactions.guid)) transactions
                on splits.tx_guid = transactions.guid)
            where accounts.code like "1010%") b
    where a.guid = b.guid;
```

As written, this query returns the expected:

```
2023-02-14 10:59:00, ACH, Name Changed, , 20000, 100, General Fund, 1010-000
2023-02-14 10:59:00, ACH, Name Changed, , 20000, 100, General Fund, 1010-000
```

But if I insert an innocuous little `union` statement at the end of the query, like

```
union select 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 from splits
```

then I get just one row back instead of two identical ones.  The `union` statement above is pointless but the real one is necessary because I am combining two different kinds of donations, and the two have different characteristics.

In my attempts to debug this, I determined that if I `select` an additional and unique column such as `a.guid` (i.e. `select date, num, description, notes, numer, denom, fund, code, a.guid from` ...), then both rows are retained.

Is there something about the `union` statement I'm misunderstanding?  Does it try to remove duplicates even when no `order by` or `group by` is involved?

Comment: ["The UNION operator works the same way as UNION ALL, except that duplicate rows are removed from the final result set."](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: Read up on the `union` and `union all` standard SQL operators, paying attention to the differences.

Comment: These comments clearly answer the question.  It's so simple in retrospect, but I wasn't aware of `union` versus `union all`  +1 to @user2722968 and @Stu.   I also came across https://stackoverflow.com/q/49925.